# notification for different users

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have an application, and there are two types of users for it one **non logged in** user and another **logged in** user. I want to notify the user with the `gcm` message for both the users accordingly. so what should be the logic behind it.

Any small hint will be helpful.

Comment: you can send any tag in data part of json. and in android side you can get that tag and check locally that user is logged in or not . and do accordingly\

Comment: before posting the question I thought of the same procedure. I thought there would be other solutions too. According to your  procedure every app installed should register the gcmregistrationid to the webhost, and at the time to sending message to gcm , server side should send the message to all the gcm registered device along with the usertype flag, and at the android side during showing the notification I have to check the usertype if the flag value matches the current state of user right ?

Comment: exactly. what is the issue in this approach ?

Comment: say if there are 1000 user with this app and only 5 are logged in.In this case if only logged in user should need to be sent the message, in this case server side app should send message to gcm server with all the 1000 registeredId. I thought it would be time lag :( So I asked

Comment: So you only need to send logged in user ?